# Unable to run AWS Lambda function with API Gateway

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have created a simple python 3.7 lambda function:

```
import json
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client("s3")


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = "nubi-data"
    key = "core/user.json"

    try:
        data = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        json_data = data['Body'].read()

        #return json_data

        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            'body': json.loads(json_data)
            }


    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise e
```

This function reads a json file from an s3 bucket. The json file looks like:

> {     "id": 1,    "name": "John",     "pwd": "password" }

The function runs successfully when I test from within function editor screen in AWS console with the following output:
[image]

> Response: {   "statusCode": 200,   "headers": {
>       "Content-Type": "application/json"   },   "body": {
>       "id": 1,
>       "name": "John",
>       "pwd": "password"   } }
>
> Request ID: "f57de02f-44dd-4854-9df9-9f3a8c90031d"
>
> Function Logs: START RequestId: f57de02f-44dd-4854-9df9-9f3a8c90031d
>   Version: $LATEST END RequestId: f57de02f-44dd-4854-9df9-9f3a8c90031d
>   REPORT RequestId: f57de02f-44dd-4854-9df9-9f3a8c90031d    Duration:
>   260.70 ms Billed Duration: 300 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 84 MB

But when I test the function from the API Gateway, I get the error
[image]

> Thu Mar 21 21:04:08 UTC 2019 : Endpoint response body before
>   transformations: {"statusCode": 200, "headers": {"Content-Type":
>   "application/json"}, "body": {"id": 1, "name": "John", "pwd":
>   "password"}} Thu Mar 21 21:04:08 UTC 2019 : Execution failed due to
>   **configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response Thu Mar 21
>   21:04:08 UTC 2019 : Method completed with status: 502**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
'body': json.loads(json_data)
```

to

```
'body': json.dumps(json_data)
```

API Gateway expects a String as output and `json.dumps` does exactly this. `json.loads`, on the other hand, creates a JSON out of a String. If you know NodeJS, they're equivalent to JSON.stringify and JSON.parse, respectively.

**Example**

```
json.dumps(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}])
```

produces

> '["foo", {"bar": ["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]'

while

```
json.loads('["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')
```

produces

> [u'foo', {u'bar': [u'baz', None, 1.0, 2]}]

This information is available in the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

**EDIT**

One more thing both the OP and I missed is that `data['Body'].read()` doesn't return the JSON itself but a buffer instead. It needs to be decoded first.

`json_data = data['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')` will return the stringified JSON already (just because your file is a JSON, of course), so on your return statement you should be able to simply do it like this:

```
return {
         'statusCode': 200,
         "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
         'body': json_data
     }
```

Comment: I tried that as well. Here is the error I get when using dumps: Thu Mar 21 22:10:53 UTC 2019 : Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable. Lambda request id: a3c6d525-d4c4-4bd0-a7fc-901a8bab8111
Thu Mar 21 22:10:53 UTC 2019 : Method completed with status: 502