# Error when trying access parameters in AWS Python Lambda function using API Gateway

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda

I have this python lambda function

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    post_user = ""
    post_user = event["user"]
    print(post_user)        

    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        "body": True
        }
```

This works as expected when I run a test within the lambda IDE. The test is configured to pass:

> {   "user": "JOHN",   "pwd": "pwd1" }

but when I run a test using the API Gateway, I get this error:

> Mon Mar 25 20:47:29 UTC 2019 : Endpoint response body before
>   transformations: {"errorMessage": "'user'", "errorType": "KeyError",
>   "stackTrace": ["  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 6, in
>   lambda_handler\n    post_user = event[\"user\"]\n"]} Mon Mar 25
>   20:47:29 UTC 2019 : Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to
>   customer function error: 'user'. Lambda request id:
>   f7955f74-e608-4b10-b216-4e4acf682307 Mon Mar 25 20:47:29 UTC 2019 :
>   Method completed with status: 502

I have defined the API gateway test as follows:
[image]

Comment: Why would you put the return statement in a try/except block?

Comment: there was a bunch of code there but got rid off before posting here. I will remove it to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Just log event and see what you getting, you can use `somedict.get('somekey') for accessing a key without raising an execption. If the key doens't exists it returns None

Comment: If you're using proxy integration you'll receive the event with a different structure: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html

Comment: This solved it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55854824/event-object-is-empty-in-aws-lambda-nodejs-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because when the `event` object comes from API Gateway, it has some extra information on it. It's not as simple as the JSON you use to test from the console.

You need to first access the `body` object and then finally your JSON object.

Here's how an event from API Gateway looks like:

```
{
    "path": "/test/hello",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, lzma, sdch, br",
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
      "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
      "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": "true",
      "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": "false",
      "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": "false",
      "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": "false",
      "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": "US",
      "Host": "wt6mne2s9k.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
      "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36 OPR/39.0.2256.48",
      "Via": "1.1 fb7cca60f0ecd82ce07790c9c5eef16c.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
      "X-Amz-Cf-Id": "nBsWBOrSHMgnaROZJK1wGCZ9PcRcSpq_oSXZNQwQ10OTZL4cimZo3g==",
      "X-Forwarded-For": "192.168.100.1, 192.168.1.1",
      "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
      "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
    },
    "pathParameters": {
      "proxy": "hello"
    },
    "requestContext": {
      "accountId": "123456789012",
      "resourceId": "us4z18",
      "stage": "test",
      "requestId": "41b45ea3-70b5-11e6-b7bd-69b5aaebc7d9",
      "identity": {
        "cognitoIdentityPoolId": "",
        "accountId": "",
        "cognitoIdentityId": "",
        "caller": "",
        "apiKey": "",
        "sourceIp": "192.168.100.1",
        "cognitoAuthenticationType": "",
        "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": "",
        "userArn": "",
        "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36 OPR/39.0.2256.48",
        "user": ""
      },
      "resourcePath": "/{proxy+}",
      "httpMethod": "GET",
      "apiId": "wt6mne2s9k"
    },
    "resource": "/{proxy+}",
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "queryStringParameters": {
      "name": "me"
    },
    "stageVariables": {
      "stageVarName": "stageVarValue"
    },
    "body": "'{\"user\":\"john\",\"pwd\":\"pwd1\"}'"
  }
```

Keep in mind that the `body` from API Gateway always comes stringified, so if you want to access it, you first need to parse this JSON string using `json.loads(event["body"])`.

Remember that the body of your *response* must be Stringified when returning to API Gateway, as we discussed on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55289870/10950867).

You can see the event sent from API Gateway in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-on-demand-https.html)

Answer (score 2):

@Thales Minussi led me to this answer but the key I'm getting from the response is different than he suggested but his suggestion is what helped me so I'm accepting it as the answer

I was getting this response. The `body` key is coming as `null`. but there were `queryStringParameters`

```
{
  "resource": "/match_creds",
  "path": "/match_creds",
  "httpMethod": "GET",
  "headers": null,
  "multiValueHeaders": null,
  "queryStringParameters": {
    "pwd": "pwd1",
    "user": "JOHN"
  },
  "multiValueQueryStringParameters": {
    "pwd": [
      "pwd1"
    ],
    "user": [
      "JOHN"
    ]
  },
  "pathParameters": null,
  "stageVariables": null,
  "requestContext": {
    "path": "/match_creds",
    "accountId": "",
    "resourceId": "",
    "stage": "test-invoke-stage",
    "domainPrefix": "testPrefix",
    "requestId": "",
    "identity": {
      "cognitoIdentityPoolId": null,
      "cognitoIdentityId": null,
      "apiKey": "test-invoke-api-key",
      "cognitoAuthenticationType": null,
      "userArn": "",
      "apiKeyId": "test-invoke-api-key-id",
      "userAgent": "",
      "accountId": "",
      "caller": "",
      "sourceIp": "test-invoke-source-ip",
      "accessKey": "",
      "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": null,
      "user": ""
    },
    "domainName": "testPrefix.testDomainName",
    "resourcePath": "/match_creds",
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "extendedRequestId": "",
    "apiId": ""
  },
  "body": null,
  "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

I changed my function to

```
import json

    def lambda_handler(event, context):

        json_data = event["queryStringParameters"] 
        user = json_data["user"]

        return {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            "body": json.dumps(user)
            }
```

Comment: Nice. I would mark yours as accepted as it reflects the reality better. I overlooked it was in the query parameters, but I’m glad I could help somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You needs to activate the setting "Use Lambda Proxy integration" under "Integration Request".

Comment: This solved it for me For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55854824/event-object-is-empty-in-aws-lambda-nodejs-function