# Cognito Pre-SignUp Trigger - Empty Lambda Event

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am trying to trigger AWS lambda code for AWS Cognito signup

My actions

1. Creted a code (AWS lambda)

```
import json
import boto3

client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name='eu-central-1')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("DEBUG: register a new user")
    str = json.dumps(event, indent=2)
    print("DEBUG EVENT: ", str) # ERROR - event is empty {}
```

2 Configured trigger (Cognito -> User pool properties -> Pre sign-up Lambda trigger)

**Problem** --  `event` function argument is empty. Why the `event` is empty?

On the other hand  I see that user was created successfully

Also I was trying to print context. But didn't find usefull information

```
DEBUG EVENT:  {}
DEBUG CONTEXT:   LambdaContext([aws_request_id=445ea5a1-8c99-4217-8dca-1ec99d01ceb5,log_group_name=/aws/lambda/setCustomAttribsP,log_stream_name=2024/03/08/[$LATEST]119c906a7f894c14bda7315aad7ad087,function_name=setCustomAttribsP,memory_limit_in_mb=128,function_version=$LATEST,invoked_function_arn=arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:011431447545:function:setCustomAttribsP,client_context=None,identity=CognitoIdentity([cognito_identity_id=None,cognito_identity_pool_id=None])])
```

I was reading this question [Event Object is empty in AWS Lambda nodejs function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55854824/event-object-is-empty-in-aws-lambda-nodejs-function)
But I didn't find Proxy settings in my AWS

I can see API Gateway --> APIs (but I don't see 'Resources' button)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the problem is related to the variable name `str`, this overwrites the built-in string datatype, which probably has side-effects.

Try this:

```py
import json
import boto3

client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name='eu-central-1')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("DEBUG: register a new user")
    event_as_str = json.dumps(event, indent=2)
    print("DEBUG EVENT: ", event_as_str) # ERROR - event is empty {}

    return event
```

The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html) tell you which information you can expect as part of the event.

If that's not it, please include the CloudWatch output so we can see the error / stack trace.

---

**Update:**

I added the `return event` line, because Lambda expects a response.

When I tested this myself and signed up a user as the administrator, this is the event I got:

```json
{
    "version": "1",
    "region": "eu-central-1",
    "userPoolId": "eu-central-1_3ylDrsZAa",
    "userName": "37a38ebf-8f59-4623-a364-1693ac23facb",
    "callerContext": {
        "awsSdkVersion": "aws-sdk-js-2.1545.0",
        "clientId": "CLIENT_ID_NOT_APPLICABLE"
    },
    "triggerSource": "PreSignUp_AdminCreateUser",
    "request": {
        "userAttributes": {
            "email_verified": "true",
            "email": "test@mail.com"
        },
        "validationData": null
    },
    "response": {
        "autoConfirmUser": false,
        "autoVerifyEmail": false,
        "autoVerifyPhone": false
    }
}
```

Maybe double-check the event sources of the Lambda function - are there other components/services that invoke it? If it's called with an empty event/payload from another service or the API Gateway, the event would be empty. For Cognito that seems so unlikely that I'd consider it impossible.

Comment: Renamed str -> event_as_str. But it didn't help
Still see ```DEBUG EVENT:  {}```

Updated my question with context output

Comment: I read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55854824/event-object-is-empty-in-aws-lambda-nodejs-function 

But I didn't find "Proxy settings ins" my AWS

Comment: The proxy settings are only relevant if you have an API Gateway in the mix. I just set up a similar function with the same setup and tried signing up a user as an admin - I got the correct event...

I added a description of my steps to reproduce and an alternative explanation.