# aws lambda error when trying to access query parameters

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm new to `aws lambda`, I created a function writen in python, i have aws `api gateway` as a trigger to my function.

the runtime is `python 3.11`

Now! here's the problem that i can't even explain:

```py
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    query = event.get('queryStringParameters', {})
    
    #that line causes the problem
    challeng = query.get('challenge', None)
    
    return {
        'statusCode':200,
        'body': 'xyz'
    }
```

and since lambdas doesn't have logs to trace the issue in the code (if any)

Comment: can you share more info -- what exactly is a problem? error message? lambdas can log or send data via print statements to the cloudwatch

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access those parameters with the following syntax

```py
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    query = event["queryStringParameters"]
    
    #that line causes the problem
    challenge = query["challenge"]
    
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": { "content-type": "application/json"},
        "body": json.dumps(challenge)
    }
```

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/a/55347344/8564731

Answer (score 0):

as i expected the issue wasn't in the code.

i simply deleted the function and created another one with the same code, guess what? it worked!